# move_uploaded_file strange behaviour that leads to a bug

Tags: php, upload

I do have a very strange behaviour while trying to upload a file via a PHP script.

First of all, here are a few infos:

- I do have the enctype set to "`multipart/form-data`" in my form
- Upload file size is set to 20M in apache config
- My upload directory `/home/www/public/files/images` have a 777 chmod

  ```
  ls -l /home/www/public/files/
  total 68K
  drwxrwxrwx. 90 pel pel 64K juin  23 18:06 images
  ```

Now, here is the code I use:

```
    if (!empty($_FILES['image'])) {

        $dir =  '/home/www/public/files/images';
        $extension = mb_strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $newfile_name = 'myimage-with-my-name.' . $extension;
        $newfile_path = $dir . '/' . $newfile_name;

        if (!is_writable($dir)) {
            throw new Exception('Upload: Cant write in ' . myescape($dir));
        }
        if (!in_array($extension, array('png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg'))) {
            throw new Exception('Upload: Unsupported extension ' . myescape($extension));
        }
        if ($_FILES['image']['error'] > 0) {
            throw new Exception('Upload: Error code ' . myescape($_FILES['image']['error']));
        }

        print_r($_FILES['image']);
        print_r(array($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newfile_path));

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newfile_path)) {
            die('ERROR: Upload Failed');
        }
    }
```

And here is the result:

```
    Array
    (
        [name] => sampleimage.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpaLjZyD
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 11721
    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => /tmp/phpaLjZyD
        [1] => /home/www/public/files/images/myimage-with-my-name.jpg
    )

    Error: Upload Failed
```

As you can see, there is no error, no "previous" exception is thrown (is_write, extension ...), and finally the `move_uploaded_file` fails.

The strange behaviour is:

- The move_uploaded_file returns false
- The image is nevertheless uploaded with the name `sampleimage.jpg` and not `myimage-with-my-name.jpg` as I wanted
- No error in the apache2 logs. I watched with tail -f during every tests

Do you have any tips or a solution to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is error reporting activated? `move_uploaded_file()` *should* throw a warning about what goes wrong. Anyway, +1 for a coherent, clean, "due diligence" type question - we get way too few of these

Comment: Well, yes, I do have error reporting activated, display_error and even html_errors. But nothing. As I said, the strange thing is that the file is uploaded but with the wrong name. Thanks for your reply Peeka ! I will double check anyway

Comment: I think you need `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newfile_path)) echo 'Your file upload was successful'; else die('ERROR: Upload Failed');` - You're including if "not" `!` then...

Comment: I just tried but th result is the same. Anyway, the "if not" test is logical.

Comment: Have a look at this, I based myself on this and works rather well: http://snipplr.com/view/14730/php-file-upload/

Comment: I think you first have to determine the uploaded file's **name** itself, for example: `$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];`, then **rename it** - I think that's where your initial problem may lie in. Have a look at the link I included above, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: `$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];` could be replaced with `$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];`.

Comment: Thanks fred for the ideas. Well, I was thinking about that, but it is strange. Let's take an example: some users have to upload an avatar. A t one moment, 2 users upload a file named "avatar.png". Even if the time frame is very small, this could lead to a collision between the "move_uploaded_file" and the "rename". Don't you think ? I will try this solution anyway.

Comment: @PierreL Ah yes I see the dilemna you're set with, and I was also faced with a very similar problem such as yours, due to people uploading images from iPhones/iPod Touch, where the default name was **image.jpg**, thus overwriting any others being uploaded afterwards. Bare with me, I think I have a script that will take care of that. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: After a try, this did not work since I do have the move_uploaded_file returning false, so script does not executes the rename placed after `if (move_uploaded_file(...)) {`

Comment: Hi, I have tried this on may machine and it goes on well, with no problems. Are you sure your server is set up good? Can you try to execute it out of general index.php, I mean in separated script? Is the same problem remains?

Comment: Well I'll try on another server that I know other scripts work. I am currently on a really standard Debian 7 with apache2+mysql running on a VM with suffisent disk space. Thanks for the clue, Ante.

Comment: mb_strtolower is for utf8, use simple strtolower. And it seems that your problem is somehwere in your final path.

Comment: @PierreL Have a look at my `pastebin.com` file, taken from a working script I have. You may have to re-work it, but it does rename the file with a timestamp and other stuff I added to it. http://pastebin.com/5NuH83cE

Comment: I just ran your script. I made few changes. Instead of mb_strtolower I use strtolower and removed your mysescape function. Everything just worked fine.

Comment: Thanks very much Fred, I'll try in combinaison withe Ante's clue. Let me the time to move another server.

Comment: @PierreL You're welcome. Keep me posted.

Comment: does the temp file get deleted? thats one of the things move__uploaded_file should be doing.

Comment: Unformtunatly, gents, no results again. Strange. I will start again from 0. Chris: yes it is since move_uploaded file uploads a file with the wrong name, that is the problem. Tell you the results of my next researches. Thanks again for your help, mates.

Comment: @PierreL Have you tried a relative path, instead of an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

the error may come from

```
 $dir =  '/home/www/public/files/images';
```

Show the path of your actual file script...
It need to be a relative path... I guess you are not on a folder before /home/

maybe it should be something like  `$dir =  './public/files/images';`

Also, you should use `if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name']))`

Comment: Well, this does not change anything. In function documentation, nothing is specified. Thaks for your answer anyway.

Comment: what is the location of this script?

Comment: It is a MVC app, so the script is included in the general index.php which is in /home/www/public . I tried with $dir = 'files/images', but it does not change anything

Comment: does `move_uploaded_file();` is allowed?

Comment: Well at least, `move_uploaded_file` is not forbidden. A `grep -nsri move_uploaded_file /etc/apache2/` returns nothing

Comment: what `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` return?

Comment: It is certainly a problem on your path... Did you tried with strtolower? Maybe your "print_f" return something you can read because your meta makes it, but maybe the path become weird inside the function

Answer (score 0):

As stated in php.net `move_uploaded_file()` is `open_basedir` aware.

`move_uploaded_file()` is both safe mode and open_basedir aware. However, restrictions are placed only on the destination path as to allow the moving of uploaded files in which filename may conflict with such restrictions. move_uploaded_file() ensures the safety of this operation by allowing only those files uploaded through PHP to be moved.

So check what is your open_basedir set to and if your dir is not below open_basedir move it below open_basedir value location.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was aware of this. open_basedir is not set safe_mode is off

Comment: Can you please try this: use relative path of the handling script location instead of full path (../images instead of /home/www/public/files/images) for destination dir. Maybe weird but tell me the result?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is `move_uploaded_file()` function issue. You can check php error log or set in your script `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

There will be no error in apache log as file there is no error - `[error] => 0` and size is `[size] => 11721`. You need to check PHP error log.

Also you can try `copy()` function just to validate that it is not a problem with `move_uploaded_file()` function.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Copy works well. ErrorReporting is set to the highest level. The problem is that move_uploaded_file fails, but upload is executed with the wrong name.